# Plone- In a dexterity.EditForm why is attempting to disable a widget causing a ConstraintNotSatisfied error?

Tags: plone, dexterity

I'm trying to disable a widget in a dexterity.EditForm, but I'm getting an error .

Here is a part of my interface class with the particular widget I want to disable

```
class IRestaurant(IPlace):

    restaurant_code = schema.TextLine(title=_(u""),
                                      required=False,
                        )
```

IPlace is a form.Schema that IRestaurant inherits from. (from plone.directives)

Here is the code I for the dexterity.EditForm class:

```
class Edit(dexterity.EditForm):
    grok.context(IRestaurant)

    def updateWidgets(self):
        super(Edit, self).updateWidgets()
        self.widgets['restaurant_code'].disabled = True
```

When I go to the edit form, I get an error:

```
ConstraintNotSatisfied: True
```

Why is this error occurring and how can I fix this?

Also, the version of Plone I am using is Plone 4.3.5.

Edit: When I tried printing the type of object that self.widgets['restaurant_code'].disabled was, it said it was a NoneType object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have better luck using the mode property.

Try something like this:

```
from z3c.form.interfaces import HIDDEN_MODE

def updateWidgets(self):
    super(Edit, self).updateWidgets()
    self.widgets['restaurant_code'].mode = HIDDEN_MODE
```

Comment: I should've used the mode property then.  I'm trying to make an edit form available to members of a role but have only have certain fields available for edit, while still showing the non-editable ones in the form. There's "write protection" that you can define (term?) above the widget in the interface, but that hides the field from the form and I want the field to be disabled, not hidden.  Your suggestion did help a lot though.  However, rather than using HIDDEN_MODE, I found DISPLAY_MODE (imported from z3c.form.interfaces).  This allowed me to display the field, while making it non-editable.